# Do I need to standardize data before applying ANOVA?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, standardization

I have designed an experiment to find out the best width of a smartphone  keyboard in terms of typing accuracy (# of mistyped letters / total # of letters typed).

Two factors were chosen for my DOE:

Factor A: People participating the experiment (4 people; small to large thumb size)

Factor B: Area of a smartphone keyboard (6 variations; all have equal width to hieght ratio)

Repetition: Each condition was repeated twice.

After conducting the experiment, I have decided to perform ANOVA to validate whether factors are statistically meaningful. However, I am not sure whether I should standardize the data with respect to Factor A. Since people have different typing speed, I thought that it would be reasonable to standardize by subtracting each person's mean and divide it by their stdev.

I am also not sure how I should interpret the ANOVA result. If A*B factor is not statistically meaningful, while A factor and B factor both are statistically meaningful, does that mean that there is an optimal keyboard size despite difference in people's thumb size? Also, what does it mean when factor A is statistically meaningful ?

So there are three questions :

1. Should I standardize the data for each person?
2. When A*B is not meaningful and B is meaningful, does that mean
       there is an optimal keyboard size for everyone?
3. What does it mean when factor A is meaningful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

A just tests whether people are different. You already knew this as otherwise you would have only used one person so it is not of any great scientific interest. If you have fitted the correct model then it has already taken out the effect of A (try just subtracting out the means and see if it makes a difference to the conclusions).

If there is no interaction between people and screens then it means that the screen difference is consistent over people.